# i want to scrape text from a image file and store it in excel

Tags: java

BOWLING O M R W  ECON 0s 45 6 WD NB Losing Dhoni as a batter always
difficult for us - Raina
TABoult 4 0 3 0 925 M 2 3 1 0 The Chennai Super Kings batsman
struck form after  lean season and
JETED 6 0 = 4 O 0 0 lauded Dhoni's support at the crease
CHMorris 4 0 4 ns o9 8 1 1 against Delhi Capitals
AR Patel 3 o 3 1 1033 6 3 2 o o “Watch the ball, hit the ball' - Dhoni's
formula for the final over
S o0 e sEoe 10 o o The CSK captain has hit 554 runs in
e PR el 227 balls inthe 20th over of an IPL
match. Thats 13% of all the runs he's
made i this tournament
. Delhi Capitals Innings (target: 180 runs from 20 overs) Talking Points - Is Dhoni babering  @EEIEER -

this one is my String
i want in excel

Comment: Maybe you start first with telling us what you are trying to achive.

Comment: "bowling o m R W ECON 0s 4s 6s wd nb " each word in a single cell then in next row Taboult 4 0 3 0 925 m2 3 10

Comment: plz @arnonuem plz help.i have no idea how to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the sparse description on what you want to do i would suggest:

1. Read the text from the image
2. Replace all spaces with a colon
   `String csvContent = imgData.replaceAll(" ",";");`
3. save text to a csv file
4. open csv file with excel

The following example assumes that you have managed to retrieve the data which is then post-processed to provide the csv format. The contents are written to a file which you can just doubleclick to see that the data is split into columns as you requested.

```java
String[] data = new String[] {
    "BOWLING O M R W ECON 0s 45 6", //notice that your OCR software does not properly recognise the string here
    "TABoult 4 0 3 0 925 M 2 3",
    "JETED 6 0 = 4 O 0 0"
};

BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter( System.getProperty( "user.home" ) + System.getProperty( "file.separator" ) + "data.csv"  ) );

for( String record : data ) {
    writer.write( record.replaceAll( " ", ";" ) );
    writer.write( "\n" );
}
writer.close();
```

Like i put in comment above, your OCR does not work correctly. I would suggest you take a look into JSOUP html parser to get the information and continue from there. Otherwise you will not be satisfied by the result.

Comment: this is how @etishree will get the lines into excel it`s an answer which fits the question.

Comment: can you plz send me the code @arnonuem..because  i want "bowling o m R W ECON 0s 4s 6s wd nb " from this each word should be present in each column

Comment: can you go to this link "https://www.espncricinfo.com/series/8048/scorecard/1178425/chennai-super-kings-vs-delhi-capitals-50th-match-indian-premier-league-2019" and see once that chennai superking bowling table i want

Comment: yes i can give you the code but you have to provide the code first which retrieves the information you posted in your question.

Comment: but @arnonuem what u r giving string[] data is we are writing in manually.how we get that thing from that string

Comment: The string is faulty - compare it with the source. If you would get the information using a html parser you could end up with a correct string which is also already delimited so that it can be easily transformed in a structure like String[].

Comment: If you stick to OCR you need to find a way or an algorithm which inserts a line break at the correct position. But as the string is right now you will not have a chance to do that. But that is not what you was asking for.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not meant to let the coding done for you completely.

Answer (score 0):

driver.get("https://www.espncricinfo.com/series/8048/scorecard/1178425/chennai-super-kings-vs-delhi-capitals-50th-match-indian-premier-league-2019");
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//article[@class='sub-module scorecard'][1]"));
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);

```
    File screen = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
   File file = new File("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\screenshot1\\screenshotOfElement2.png");
    FileHandler.copy(screen, file);
    
    ITesseract instance = new Tesseract();
    instance.setDatapath("C:\\selenium_work\\ScrapingText.PDF\\tessdata");
    String result = instance.doOCR(file);
    //System.out.println(result);
    String[] lines  = result.split("\\n");
    this one what am trying
```